# How to make a color palette from colors in a loaded image

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, color-palette

I'm trying to create a color palette like the one in photoshop or the one in any application that allows a user to choose from a set of colors that are typically 25px x 25px square color boxes.

I'm spending time getting to know the bitmap palette in c# windows forms and or the graphics and bitmap objects.

What I am trying to do is create a palette that is no wider that 400px and no higher than 400px that has all the colors from a given image organized and stacked next to and on top of each other to produce that color palette effect.

So far this is what I've got.

**Here is my code:**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\sample.png";
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Image image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
            stream.Close();

            var colors = image.Palette.Entries;
            int cntColors = colors.Count();
            int half = cntColors / 2;

            Bitmap platte = new Bitmap(half * 50, half * 50);
            Graphics dc = Graphics.FromImage(platte);

            int currX = 0,
                currY = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < cntColors; i++)
            {
                SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(colors[i].A, colors[i].R, colors[i].G, colors[i].B));

                dc.FillRectangle(brush, currX, currY, 50, 50);

                if (currX == platte.Width)
                {
                    currX = 0;
                    currY += 50;
                }
                else
                {
                    currX += 50;
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = platte;
        }
```

**Here is a snapshot of what this code is producing with the image i've loaded from the bin folder.**

[image]

**Here is the image that I'm loading and using for the colors.**

[image]

This is not for anything specific I'm just working with this and trying to get a better understand of how to pull all the colors from an image, organize them in a palette, and then display the palette to the user.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate a palette of prominent colors from an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823854/how-can-i-generate-a-palette-of-prominent-colors-from-an-image)