# sorting images by color

Tags: php, image, rgb, histogram

I'm looking for a way to sort images as in the following screenshot:

http://www.pixolution.de/sites/LargeImages_en.html

I've looked at all the threads on this topic on stackoverflow but none of the proposed solutions even come close to giving me the image above.

Approaches I've tried:

1. for each image, build histogram of rgb colors in descending order of occurrence
2. for each histogram, calculate a distance from black (r:0,g:0,b:0) as follows:

   ```
   for color in image_histogram:
     total_distance += color.percentage_of_image * distance(BLACK_RGB, color.rgb)
   ```

then sort images by their distances

I was hoping that images of similar color distribution would end up with a similar distance and result in a visual ordering by color. This was not the case, it seems to somewhat work but not like in the image above.

For the distance function, I've tried euclidean distance, hsv sorting (h->s->v) and even Lab distance sorting. None of which has helped

If anyone has a better approach, I would love to know!

Comment: This isn't tagged as python, but that for loop in the middle sure looks like python.

Comment: In both PHP and canvas with HTML5 and javascript, you can get the average rgb color of an image. From there you would add all the values together and divide by 3 to get the lightness of your image. You would arrange all the values along the y axis from light to dark, and do a hue shift from r to g to b along the x axis. Just an idea, after I finish my current project, I might work on this, thanks for the idea!

Comment: thanks Vap0r, here is a clearer example of what I'm looking for:
http://www.pixolution.de/sites/LargeImages_en.html

Comment: The link in the question is broken

Answer (score 2):

I've never done something like this myself, so forgive me if the following approach is naive:

- For each image, boil it down to 1 average RGB value by summing the R, G, B values of all pixels, and divide by the total # pixels. Normalize the components to [0..1]
- Plot the image in your 2D color space based on the RGB values. This can be a 2D projection of a 3D (r, g, b) vector transformation.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along these lines as well.  What he describes is a projection down to 1D.  The example photo certainly looks like it is projecting to 2D.  I was toying with something like this: `x= h*s`, `y=v*s` as the projection.  But there might be something better.

Comment: interesting, I'll give both approaches a shot

Answer (score 2):

you could convert to HSV and sort by H

Hue is what most people think of when they think "color"

see: [RGB to HSV in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773698/rgb-to-hsv-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Group similar colors using the distance between them and not between them and black, and use the average color in the image.

Comment: I think median color instead of average would work better, otherwise some edge cases will look out of place. Unless that's what he wants of course, hard to see on his example.

Comment: Looking for dominant color. This link suggests using the maximal point on a "smoothed" histogram: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205244/get-average-color-from-bmp

but I don't understand what the approach they describe for smoothing it

Comment: The suggested method in the link is a simple blur achieved by averaging the pixels. I believe the linked question answers your queryy btw.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out ImagePlot. I'm not sure if the algorithms behind the system are available, but you can certainly download and run your image collection through the free software to analyze them.

This software is used in many interesting visualizations of massive image collections, millions+

Info: http://lab.softwarestudies.com/p/imageplot.html#whatsnew
Source: https://github.com/culturevis/imageplot